# Ordenar arquivos de um diretório com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um diretório onde estão armazenados os arquivos da seguinte forma:

```
atos-oficiais-11-11-2019.pdf
atos-oficiais-14-10-2019.pdf
atos-oficiais-15-12-2019.pdf
....
```

Desenvolvemos um sistema para que esses arquivos sejam cadastrados no banco de dados à partir de janeiro/2020, porém para não fazermos isso já nos 600 arquivos existentes no diretório, criamos o seguinte código:

```
$pasta = 'atos-oficiais/';
if(is_dir($pasta))
{
    $diretorio = dir($pasta);
    while(($arquivo = $diretorio->read()) !== false)
    {
         $quebrar = explode('atos-oficiais-',$arquivo);
         $extensao = explode('.',$quebrar[1]);
         list($dia,$mes,$ano) = explode('-',$extensao[0]);
         $data = $ano.'-'.$mes.'-'.$dia;
         if($data != '--')
         {
            $diasemana = array('Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado');
            $dataSemana = $data;
            $diasemana_numero = date('w', strtotime($dataSemana));
            mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO atos_oficiais VALUES(null,
                                    0,
                                    '".$data."',
                                    '".$diasemana[$diasemana_numero]."',
                                    '".$arquivo."')");
            $id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
            $cod = md5(strrev($id));
            mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE atos_oficiais SET IdCodAtosOficiais = '".$cod."' WHERE IdAtosOficiais = '".$id."';");                        
         }
    }
    $diretorio->close();
}
 else
{
    echo 'A pasta não existe.';
}
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente, porém percebemos que os arquivos estão sendo cadastrados de forma aleatória e precisamos ordenar os arquivos pela data de forma crescente, ou seja, dos mais antigos para os arquivos mais recentes. Já tentei ordenar diretamente pelo gerenciador de arquivos (estou usando o Linux), mas não adiantou. Como posso fazer ordená-los antes de incluí-los no BD?

Comment: Poderia usar um `sort(glob($pasta))`.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer isso seria utilizar a função "scandir", ela já retorna o nome dos arquivos em ordem alfabética. Aqui tem um exemplo

```
<?php
$caminho = "nome_da_pasta";
// Selecionar tudo exceto arquivos ocultos
$arquivos = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($caminho)); 

foreach ($arquivos as $arquivo) {
    print_r($arquivo . "<br>");
}
?>
```

Comment: Olá Bins. Na verdade não seria por ordem alfabética, já que todos os arquivos começam com a letra "a".

Answer (score -1):

Poderia fazer uma metodo ou função para ler o diretório e retornar os arquivos já ordenados, e depois chamar a função ou metodo para incluir passando o array com uma lista dos documentos já ordenados.
Algo dessa forma

```
while(($arquivo = $diretorio->read()) !== false) {
   $arquivos[] = $arquivo
}

arsort($arquivos);
```

Depois chamar uma função para inserir passando o array $arquivos como parametro